PHP Apache problem with redirect URL - htaccess
I have a problem on my Laravel project using Apache. I am trying to access some network shared folders this way:
$directory = "\\fileserver\public\office\technology";
$items = scandir($directory);

I got this link right here (/office/technology) and it works!
Then when I click for a redirect it doesn't work using Apache service (404 Apache error).
I googled some results and I think that's an .htaccess or http-vhosts.conf configuration error.
.htaccess
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

httpd-vhosts.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.vr.it
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/intranet/public"
    ErrorLog "logs/test.vr.it-error.log"
    <Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/intranet/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

I also have mod_rewrite enabled but I get 404 error. Can someone help me?
Thanks a lot
It works only with php artisan serve command so it's an apache configuration error

php artisan serve uses php in the background to have a server, it does not use apache at all. Never use php artisan serve, always use apache or nginx (use Sail if you don't know how to create your own local environment for development using Docker Compose)

what about permissions ? like the apache is likely ran as service with different permissions then the php artisan serve which have local user permissions

@matiaslauriti im using Apache, I was just saying that the code is correct cause it works with artisan serve

@Kazz permissions are good cause I can see the main folders, the problem is I can't get inside the subfolders

some ideas? please

each folder/file has its own permissions, fact that you see main folders do not prove that permissions are good

solved how ? post answer to help others with same issue
